# SharePoint 2010 Root Site Collection (overwrite) - restoration options?

Tags: collection

Totally embarrassing - a sub-site from our staging environment was imported targeting the production environment's root site collection instead of the sub-site. Needless to say, I have a big problem.

I can see the sub-sites, so I am assuming that I can (1) perform granular backups, (2) perform a full farm restoration, and (3) restore the newly created backups of the sub-sites.  Does my logic make sense? I am trying my best not to perform a full config and content restoration to insure that no data was lost since the last backup.

Will "newbie of the year"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how you trying to restore the sub-site into top level?
why you need to restore the subsite once you already have full farm restoration?
 if you just need the Subsite restore than you dont need to perform the full farm restore

take a look on the following blog to understand the process:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2009/10/21/sharepoint-2010-granular-backup-restore-part-1.aspx

Comment: Wagas, thank you for your response.  I am attempting to restore the root site collection - not promote a sub-site into the top level.  Pardon my ignorance (recently assumed this role due to attrition). After more research, I see that my logic was severely flawed.  Since I have the same structure in a staging environment, I should be able to export the top collection from staging into the top collection in production - correct?  Again, thanks for your time and concern.

Comment: Yes you can do it. But instead of exporting, use the site collection backup & restore it. Use this link for Backup(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901(v=office.15).aspx) and for restore use this(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thanks again - one last question - using the backup method suggested is granular only - correct?  I don't want to restore at the top and erase the sub-sites that still exist.

Comment: backup & Restore method i mentioned is, if you want to copy whole site collection. But if you want to move just subsite then Import & export will work.

Comment: Ok - I think I am closer to understanding the difference between the two methods.  One last clarification - if I backup site root (http://site_test/) to (http//site_production/), will it wipe out the following (http://site_production/A/ or http://site_production/B/)?  I guess my question is 'does the backup method include subs and folders.'  You help has been greatly appreciated.

Comment: if A & B are subsite of the (Site_Production) then yes it will wipe out But if A & B are independent Site collections then no...You can check from Central Admin if A & B are site collctions or sub sites...Central Admin> Application Management > View All site collections> select the web app and if you see A & B on this page then these are independent site collections